# Oracle - Hot to get rid from gmt while combining 2 dates?

Tags: datetime-format

I'm new in Oracle. I have 2 columns :

```
ITEM_DAILY.DATE_SCD = '2024-01-17 00:00:00'

ITEM_DAILY.TIME_SCD = '1030'
```

I'm trying to combine between them :

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(XCREW.ITEM_DAILY.DATE_SCD ,'dd-mm-yyyy') ||' '|| XCREW.ITEM_DAILY.TIME_SCD,'dd-mm-yy hh24mi') AS TIME_SCD,
```

Expecting:

```
TIME_SCD = '2024-01-17 10:30:00'

In fact , getting : 

TIME_SCD = '2024-01-17 10:30:00+02:00'
```

How can I avoid the +02:00 GMT postfix?

Answer (score 0):

You could do

`cast(TIME_SCD as timestamp with time zone) at time zone 'UTC'`

This converts the TIME_SCD to a timestamp with your current time zone (the one that is defined by your client through SESSIONTIMEZONE) and then converts that to UTC.

Comment: Thanks Tim, Just to clarify : I don't want to have time zone in the result , I need a "clean" result. Expecting : TIME_SCD = '2024-01-17 10:30:00'